# how insert column of same number in text file?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl

I have input file like::: a.txt

```
1  0.4 0.8
2  0.5 3.0
5  0.8 3.5
```

I want output like this::: 1.txt

```
1 3 0.4 0.8
2 3 0.5 3.0
5 3 0.8 3.5

1 8 0.4 0.8
2 8 0.5 3.0
5 8 0.8 3.5
```

I want to add same number in second column.in loop
how can i do this??

Comment: Where did the numbers 3 and 8 in the second column come from?

Comment: this is not 3,itz 5 only by mistake it happen.

Comment: i want a loop like this, which can add number that is given in loop let say for ((i=1; i<=10;i++))..... so that i = whatever number should come in coulmn second. like I have added 3 and 8

Comment: please *edit* your question for additionnal information, comment are not indented and hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `awk` to get the expected output,

```
for i in {3,8}; do awk -v a=$i '{print $1,a,$2,$3}' a.txt; echo "" ; done >  1.txt
```

**Explanation:**

Here `-v` option (`var=value`) is used to pass any variable to awk

`print {$1,a,$2,$3}` , here `a` is the variable that you want in the second column, the rest all columns are printed as they are

Answer (score 1):

You need three nested loops

```
for n in 3 8 ; do
    while read -a cols ; do
        printf '%s %s' "${cols[0]}" $n
        for ((i=1; i<=${#cols[@]}; i++)) ; do
            printf ' %s' "${cols[i]}"
        done
        echo
    done <a.txt
    echo
done > 2.txt
```

You can also use sed:

```
for n in 3 8 ; do
    sed "s/ / $n /" a.txt
    echo
done > 1.txt
```

Comment: for ((i=2000; i<=2000; i++))
do
for ((j=9; j<=9; j++))
do
awk '{print $1, $j, $2}' triplet_mlecule_number-"$i"-"$j".ndx > insert-"$i"-"$j".txt
done
done
hey.... I want to print this j in loop in second column, it can be any number in j.

Comment: @claudiasmith you can use `-v` option to use any variable defined outside awk, in your case , just assign j to a local variable of awk by using -v option 
`for ((i=2000; i<=2000; i++)) do for ((j=9; j<=9; j++)) do awk -v a=$j '{print $1, a, $2}' triplet_mlecule_number-"$i"-"$j".ndx > insert-"$i"-"$j".txt `
I have included an example in my answer too, check if it solves your problem

Comment: Do you really want to iterate from 2000 to 2000 and from 9 to 9?